# AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'PySparkRuntimeError' as I try to apply .collect() to some RDD.map(...).distinct()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am a beginner with Spark.

I am running spark on local machine, with no cluster.

I have developed the following script.

The aim is to get the unique values of the keys "license".

Everything goes well past the lines

```
licenses_collected = rdd.map(lambda x: x["license"]).collect()
unique_licenses = rdd.map(lambda x: x["license"]).distinct()
```

but as I try to apply the `.distinct()` method to the mapped rdd and then apply the `.collect()` method, the Traceback is raised.

This is the line which raises the error

```
unique_licenses_collected = rdd.map(lambda x: x["license"]).distinct().collect()
```

What is the problem?

### script

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local").\
    appName("prima applicazione spark").\
    config("spark.ui.port", "4040").\
    getOrCreate()

df_spark = spark.read.json(path_json)
rdd = df_spark.rdd
rdd_collected = rdd.collect()


"""Get the first two records"""

for line in rdd.take(2):
    print(line)

print("\n\n")


""" Get the name of the licenses"""

licenses_collected = rdd.map(lambda x: x["license"]).collect()

unique_licenses = rdd.map(lambda x: x["license"]).distinct()

unique_licenses_collected = rdd.map(lambda x: x["license"]).distinct().collect()
```

### Traceback

> AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'PySparkRuntimeError' on <module
> 'pyspark.errors.exceptions.base' from
> '/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/errors/exceptions/base.py'>

[full traceback here](https://github.com/tommasosansone91/miscellaneous_logs/blob/main/canteget_PySparkRuntimeError_traceback.txt)

### programs versions

```
pyspark --version
version 3.4.2

python --version
Python 3.10.12
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is caused by spark version 3.4.2.

Upgrading the spark version from 3.4.2 to 3.5.1 solved the problem

### spark upgrade procedure

remove old spark version

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/spark/
```

download [Apache Spark 3.5.1 tgz archive](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-3.5.1/spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz) into `Downloads/`

unpack the archive

```
tar xvf spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3.tgz
```

move the file to install optimized directory

```
sudo mv spark-3.5.1-bin-hadoop3 /opt/spark
```

in case you did not have spark on your machine before, add environment variables

```
vim ~/.bashrc
```

paste this

```
# per spark
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/spark
export PATH=$PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin
```

reload the file

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

check that the installed verison is the 3.5.1

```
pyspark --version
```